# Как при помощи API Google Analytics получить все просмотры и визиты пользователей?

Tags: google-analytics

Как при помощи API Google Analytics получить все просмотры и визиты пользователей?

В Яше есть вот такое Logs API: https://tech.yandex.ru/metrika/doc/api2/logs/queries/getlogrequests-docpage/

В аналитике гугла как такое получить?

Comment: Если речь не про код, а про ссылку на доку, то у Гугла *тоже* есть поиск.

Comment: Поиск тут не причем. Нужно понять как получить все визиты всех пользователей. Так называемый Log-views

Comment: Ну то есть ты полагаешь, что у GA API отсутствует документация, которую можно найти поиском. Интересная точка зрения

Comment: ну то есть я полагаю, что тут есть люди которые делали похожую задачу и поняли как преодолеть автогруппировку. Но пока вижу школьника, который ничего не знает, но пытается умничать. Убеги флудить в другое место, плиз

Comment: Если у тебя есть конкретная проблема с автогруппировкой, то ее и надо описывать в вопросе.

Comment: Я не уверен в чем именно проблема. Я указал пример в YaM API. В гугле тоже есть такое, но как обычно они все запутали и усложнили.

Comment: Поэтому сижу разбираюсь и пытаюсь понять. Потому как все визиты у меня суммируются и вообще все суммируется, а не возвращается инфа по каждому визиту.